# How to move products title in products view page magento 2 using custom theme?

Tags: magento2

> Actually i want to move products title in products view page using
>   custom theme in magento 2

Comment: Have you got solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

Find below file.

> app/design/frontend/yourTheme/magento_catalog/catalog_product_view.xm

And add below code

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="content" after="product.info.media"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chirag Patel's answer is correct. But I use it in the following way.

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
```